# Получение минут и секунд из полного времени в виде строки

Tags: c++, windows

Есть функция `_tctime`, которая форматирует число в строку следующего формата:

> день.месяц.год часы:минуты:секунды

А какая функция форматирует в формате

> минуты:секунды.

```
int tileLeft = 113;
TCHAR caption[100] = {};
_tcscpy_s(caption, _tctime(&tileLeft));
caption[_tcslen(caption) - 1U] = TEXT('\0');
```

Comment: просто минуты секунды? без года и месяца?

Comment: да, только минуты и секунды

Comment: Тут есть проблема - функция _tcscpy_s копирует строку, но не делает форматирование. Покажите полный код и несколько примеров входных и выходных данных, которые Вам нужны.

Comment: `/ 60` и `% 60` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для более полной настройки формата строки времени можно использовать функции типа [`strftime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fe06s4ak.aspx). При этом стоит отметить, что [`ctime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/59w5xcdy.aspx) работает с `time_t` ([UNIX time](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)). И итог есть не *интервал* времени, а *точка* во времени от 1970 года.

Если же Ваша переменная просто содержит кол-во секунд, и нужно вывести это значение как минуты и секунды - самый простой вариант ограничиться делением, как это уже было предложено в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634456/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8#comment894826_634456):

```
timeLeft / 60 -> минуты
timeLeft % 60 -> секунды
```